# C# How do I get the name of a Directory instead of a path?

Tags: c#, .net, directory

I am trying to get the enclosing directory from a path:

```
DsVersions.ASSEMBLY2Row row = dsVersions.ASSEMBLY2.NewASSEMBLY2Row();
row.FOLDER = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName);
```

What I get is the *full path*:

```
@"C:\Program Files (x86)\EdisonFactory\NetOffice\Plugins"
```

And what I need is just `Plugins`.

I think that I need to use Substring but I am not sure where or how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.name) for help:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName));
row.FOLDER = dir.Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

From your path you could do this:

```
new FileInfo(fileName).Directory.Name
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, a quick way of doing it is:

```
row.Folder = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(filename));
```

`GetFileName` simply gets the last string after the last separator.

Comment: Unless `GetDirectoryName` returns `C:`.

Comment: @sixlettervariables `GetDirectoryName` won't return a value of `C:` If the file in question is `C:\MyFile.tmp`, `GetDirectoryName` returns `C:\ ` and `GetFileName` then returns an empty string.

Comment: You're right it returns "C:\", but what I meant to point out is that now `row.FOLDER` no longer has the folder with the file (i.e. it doesn't point to anywhere, just an empty string).